# How to calculate direction vector(v) with up to three points on a plane

Tags: matrices, vectors

3 points on a plane acquired empirically:

Point $P: (65.143, 407.19, 1.000)$
Point $Q: (624.608, 359.191,1.000)$
Point $R: (69.766, 82.885, 1.000)$

In the following equation that solves for an intersect point between a ray(line) and a plane, how do I calculate $\vec v$, the direction vector, from the three planar points from above?
$$t = \frac{-(n\cdot p + d)}{v\cdot n}$$

Vector/Line the above equation uses:

$$p = po + t\vec v$$

Vector plane equation used above:
$$\vec n \cdot \vec p + d = 0$$
$$\vec n \cdot (\vec po + t\vec v)+ d = 0$$
$$(\vec po\cdot \vec n)+(t\vec v\cdot\vec n)= -d $$
$$ t\vec v \cdot  \vec n=-(\vec po \cdot \vec n +d)$$

$$t = \frac{=-(\vec po \cdot \vec n +d)}{\vec n\cdot v}$$

Solving for t denominator:

```
float denom = n.dot(v);
v(l,m,n) = ?
```

Comment: V is any vector in the direction of line for which you wish to calculate point of intersection. If these three points lie in the plane then from them you will get n and d. V and p you will get from the line for which you wish to calculate point of intersection with the plane.

Comment: Yes, r = ro + tv. Do I use vector PR or PQ for V? Or the point P on the plane minus the origin (0,0,0)?

Comment: Could I extend a ray from the origin(0,0,0) to P, Q or R on the plane; and have my direction vector?

Comment: Well if P,Q, and R lie in the plane then lines PQ, QR and RP doesn't make sense as.then point of intersection will then be these lines itself. Also, OP,.OQ.and OR doesn't make much sense as then point of intersection will then be P,Q and R respectively. If you can share the complete context of the question or the question itself then it might help

Comment: Sure, complete context: I want to solve for t and having some troubles finding all of the unknowns: I've have 3 planar points on hand . I've got n(cross product of PQ,PR), d(-n.r) and I think p0(0,0,0)? leaving v to find.

Comment: Graphic updated